# Is two-way binding supported on MVVMCross for Touch? (besides UITextFields)

Tags: mvvmcross

I was looking at reasons why my 2-way binding hasn't been working for iOS development using MVVMCross.  I'm using UITextViews embedding in custom cells of a tableView.

I've looked at this question:

[How do I do two-way binding to a UITextView control using mvvmcross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839310/how-do-i-do-two-way-binding-to-a-uitextview-control-using-mvvmcross)

and there was mention on how 2-way binding with UITextViews isn't supported in Vnext, but it is in beta with V3 (Hot Tuna).  I am using Hot Tuna, and got the binaries approx. June 12th.

The following line of code is how I'm binding my cell.

```
this.CreateBinding (_cells[2]).For (cll => cll.FieldDescription).To ((TimesheetViewModel vm) => vm.AccountID).Mode(MvxBindingMode.TwoWay).Apply ();
```

_cells[] is an array of custom class cells

Here's the property of FieldDescription in my custom cell class:  (FieldDescriptionLabel is my UITextView)

```
    public string FieldDescription
    {
        get
        { 
            return FieldDescriptionLabel.Text;
        }
        set 
        {
            FieldDescriptionLabel.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

My UITextView binds one way; I do see the information populated from my viewModel, but when I change something in the UITextView, the ViewModel doesn't reflect those changes.

So the main question:  Is 2-way binding working for UITextView in MVVMCross Hot Tuna?  If yes, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong in my implementation?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for two-way binding to work, mvvmcross needs to know when the ui value changes.

There are a couple of ways to do this.

Perhaps the easiest way, given your current setup, is to add a `public event EventHandler FieldDescriptionChanged` to your cell and to make sure this event is fired every time the text view changes - e.g. with code like.

```
public event EventHandler FieldDescriptionChanged;

public string FieldDescription
{
    get
    { 
        return FieldDescriptionLabel.Text;
    }
    set 
    {
        FieldDescriptionLabel.Text = value;
    }
}

public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib();

    FieldDescriptionLabel.Changed += (s,e) => {
        var handler = FieldDescriptionChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    };
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could try basing your cell on the `Mvx` table view cells which have an inherent `DataContext`. If you do this, then you can bind directly to the `UITextView` with and then using data-binding within the cell's context.

This approach is shown in the N+1 tutorials - for example in N=6.5 - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n6-books-over-network-n1-days-of.html - where the cell ends up with a constructor like:

```
public BookCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    _loader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => MainImage);

    this.DelayBind(() => {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<BookCell, BookSearchItem> ();
        set.Bind(TitleLabel).To (item => item.volumeInfo.title);
        set.Bind (AuthorLabel).To (item => item.volumeInfo.authorSummary);
        set.Bind (_loader).To (item => item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail); 
        set.Apply();
    });
}
```

Using this approach, you would simply need to bind the cell's data context - e.g. something like:

```
   this.CreateBinding (_cells[2]).For (cll => cll.DataContext).To ((TimesheetViewModel vm) => vm).TwoWay().Apply ();
```

Comment: I was flagging my own event, but I didn't realize 2-way would work if I named it "FieldDescriptionChanged".  My fix before asking this question was flagging a "FieldChanged" event and then monitoring it and manually updating my ViewModel.